# ngModel forcing get properties twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple component to display a list of items. I have a ngfor loop and inside it a checkbox with a `[(ngModel)]`. Everything works as expected.

```
<div *ngFor="let armor of armorList">    
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="armor.obtained"  />
    <span>{{armor.name}}</span>
</div>
```

I have create a get property called name like below. (I have removed the implementation itself just for the example)

```
 get name(): string {
        console.log("test");
        return "test";
    }
```

What I think is odd is that, if I click on the checkbox of one item on the list, this get property is being called for all the items on the list twice. I would assume that it should not be called at all, since I am just updating one property of one item, not related to the rest.

https://plnkr.co/edit/KqDpuw1QeXOCFNODbqiW?p=preview
I have create the example above. If you click on one of the checkbox you can see that "test" is being displayed 6 times on the console.

Any ideas?

Regards

Leo

Answer (score 1):

That's because angular rechecks the model again after updating the views to verify that it hasn't changed. This is done to ensure the stability of the model and that updating the view doesn't update the model again and you start an infinite loop. If angular finds that the model has changed after updating, it will throw `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

Note that this only happens in development mode.

For further reading : [see this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: I got the twice check. But why it updates all the other items on the list? I would be ok if just the item that I clicked gets updated, but why all the others on the list?

Comment: it's because your application state has changed so angular needs to recheck the model and update the view, you can read more here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#what-causes-change

Answer (score 0):

It will be called twice only in the *development mode* for verifying that the moel has not been changed. If model will be changed in the second call, it will throw error. So you can detect the wrong cases at the development stage. When you build your bundles in the *production mode*, it will call once.

Comment: I got the twice check. But why it updates all the other items on the list? I would be ok if just the item that I clicked gets updated, but why all the others on the list?

Comment: Change detection is runned for all bounded items. Maybe clicking one item will change another one, so why it runs for all of them